# JavaFX: How to disable multi-line option of TextArea

Tags: java, csv, javafx

I have an application which write and reads from csv file. I have a TextArea in my program, but when I type some multiline text, the csv file is broken then and app is unable to launch, because it cannot read from it.

Here's what I use for save and load.

```
public void save() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path))) {
        for (Tasks o : (getTasks())) {
            bw.write(o.getTask() + ";" +
                    o.getDeadline().toString() + ";" +
                    o.getDescription());
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
}

public void load() throws IOException, ParseException {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            List<Tasks> tempTasks = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(";");
                String task = parts[0];
                LocalDate deadline = LocalDate.parse(parts[1]);
                String desc = parts[2];
                tempTasks.add(new Tasks(task, deadline, desc));
            }
            tasks.clear();
            tasks.addAll(tempTasks);
        }
    } else
        tasks.clear();
}
```

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

How csv file looks:

[image: how csv file looks]

Comment: Can you please share a [complete working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Here's the whole repo: https://github.com/vholub/ukolnicek-mp3-git Unfortunately I do not know what exactly should I give as example :(

Comment: A simple code snippet that shows your issue and everyone can simply reproduce it with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the new line characters before saving, because they destroy your csv file, as you already mentioned.

You could use `description.replace("\n", "\\n")` to escape on save and `description.replace("\\n", "\n")` to unescape on load.

```
public void save() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path))) {
        for (Tasks o : (getTasks())) {
            bw.write(o.getTask() + ";" +
                    o.getDeadline().toString() + ";" +
                    o.getDescription().replace("\n", "\\n"));
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
}

public void load() throws IOException, ParseException {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            List<Tasks> tempTasks = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(";");
                String task = parts[0];
                LocalDate deadline = LocalDate.parse(parts[1]);
                String desc = parts[2].replace("\\n", "\n");
                tempTasks.add(new Tasks(task, deadline, desc));
            }
            tasks.clear();
            tasks.addAll(tempTasks);
        }
    } else
        tasks.clear();
}
```

But using a `;` in your title or description would also screw up your csv.

I would suggest using an external library for csv handling, e.g. [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). Alternatively you could save your tasks in another text format like json or xml.

Comment: Thank you very much. Recently I used to use only json and to be honest, I do not know why I wanted to try csv this time.

Also `;` cannot be in title thanks to this in constructor (but it is not the best solution as you mentioned) `if(task.contains(";"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();`

Comment: @VratislavHolub JSON & XML are for data of a hierarchical nature or of an arbitrary structure (not always the same fields in all instances). In contrast, [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [Tab-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) formats are for [flat tabular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database) data, simple columns and rows.

Comment:  for using a library such as *Apache Common CSV* for such chores of reading/writing CSV/TDF files.